# FTX api. "error":"Missing parameter coin"

Tags: python, cryptocurrency

I want to make withdrawal request using aiohttp. I made the correct signature and request-data, but in response I got error "Missing parameter coin".

```
async def main(coin, amount, address, method):

# I entered TRX, 0.01, TXKbit45oBWoJHcE25NQPYhsHV5P8EqJvN, trx

ts = int(time.time() * 1000)

data = {
    "coin": coin,  # TRX
    "size": amount,  # 0.01
    "address": address,  # TXKbit45oBWoJHcE25NQPYhsHV5P8EqJvN
    "method": method  # trx
}

signature_payload = f'{ts}POST/api/wallet/withdrawals{json.dumps(data)}'.encode()
signature = hmac.new(API_SECRET.encode(), signature_payload, 'sha256').hexdigest()

headers = {
    "FTX-KEY": API_KEY,
    "FTX-TS": str(ts),
    "FTX-SIGN": signature
}

session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
withdrawal = await session.post("https://ftx.com/api/wallet/withdrawals",
                                headers=headers,
                                data=json.dumps(data))
print(await withdrawal.text())
# {"success":false,"error":"Missing parameter coin","errorCode":"parameter_missing"}
await session.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

That helped me

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
from urllib import parse
from yarl import URL

async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        params={"q":"Привет","source":"auto","target":"en","format":"text"}
        url='http://localhost:5000/translate?' + parse.urlencode(params)
        async with session.post(URL(url,encoded=True)) as resp:
            print(resp.status)
            print(await resp.text())
asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Could you explain why this works?